# I’ve seen several types that look similar. What type of aloe am I?

Tags: identification, houseplants

[image]

Is it sunburnt? Is that why I’m having trouble identifying it?

Answer (score 2):

I think your plant is an aloe relative with the common name of Haworthia. The genus *Haworthia* has been split in recent years into *Haworthia*, *Haworthiopsis* and *Tulista*. Your plant resembles [Haworthiopsis venusta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haworthiopsis_venosa#/media/File:Haworthia_venosa_MBB_Felix_unite_2.jpg), so may be a related species.

There are two related genera, *Gasteria* and *Astroloba*. If you combine all these genera, you're probably looking at over 200 possible species.

Fortunately, culture for all of these is pretty much the same: Give only a little water weekly or a little more water every other week and don't let the pot sit in a saucer full of water. Or you can just ignore it and water it when you notice it and when the pot feels pretty light. I keep mine in terra cotta pots to help keep them dry. I also keep my own haworthia in morning-only sun. My plants occasionally bloom; some species apparently have showy flowers, mine does not. The flowers would be a helpful key to identification.

The plants are easy to propagate. I wait until they've filled a pot, then unpot it and split some "pups" off of it. They root readily if just placed on top of the soil.

Comment: Yes, and I've seen it labeled Star Aloe.

Comment: @YosefBaskin That whole Asphodelaceae family can get quite confusing - it's like going down a rabbit hole to try to ID anything.